# Webpack IE9 require() breaks scripts

Tags: internet-explorer-9, webpack, vue.js

This is the code I have on my site:

http://jsfiddle.net/aLxfnj97/1/

It works great even in IE9 through JSFiddle, but when I compile it with Webpack, my code will ONLY use the default values.. they won't update in the Vue js ready methods, click methods, nothing.

HTML:

```
<div class="locator">
    <div class="locator-wrapper">
        <a title="Dealer Locator" v-class="active" href="locator">Dealer Locator</a>
        <div class="zip-dropdown" v-class="slide">
            <form action="/" method="post">
                <input name="zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code">
                    <button name="search-locator" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Vue:

```
var DealerLocator = new Vue({
    el: '.locator',

    data: {
        slide: 'slideUp',
        active: 'inactive'
    },

    ready: function() {
        var self = this;

        $(this.$el).on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                self.slide = 'slideDown';
                self.active = 'activated';
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                self.slide = 'slideUp';
                self.active = 'inactive';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The CSS is irrelevant because I'm inspecting the element WHILE hovering over it and the class won't change, but in the fiddle it will change on IE9. It works great in Chrome, Firefox, IE10+, but it won't work in IE9. I compile this script with Webpack. THIS IS THE ISSUE. When I have the code directly in the app.js file, it works. But when I `require()` it, it won't work.

My main app.js file looks like this:

```
var Vue = require('vue');

require('./instances/locator/DealerLocator');
```

This is how my webpack config looks:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './resources/assets/js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './public/build/js',
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.styl$/, loader: "css" },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help. I'm not sure why it reads the Vue modules, but it won't update the properties of them in any of the methods.